# Json Array for highchart

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, highcharts

```
[{"outlet":"K-SM3","tanggal":"2016-06-02","total":5083600},
 {"outlet":"K-SM3","tanggal":"2016-06-01","total" :4660500},
 {"outlet":"K-PKM","tanggal":"2016-06-02","total":1576250},
 {"outlet":"K-PKM","tanggal":"2016-06-01" ,"total":921300}]
```

I'm currently learning about highchart. Above are my result from `console.log`, i'm using ajax to show somedata. But no luck, the chart not showing up. I can't find error inside `console.log`.

My PHP Script

```
function onchange()
    {
        extract(populateform());
        $explode = explode('-',$tgl);
        $start_date = inggris_date($explode[0]);
        $end_date = inggris_date($explode[1]);
        $jumlah = count($datanya);
        $result = array();
        for($x = 0 ;$x<$jumlah;$x++)
            {
                $hasil = $this->modelmodel->showdata("select outlet,convert(date,tanggal)tanggal,(cash + cc + dc + flash + piutang + reject + disc50)
                                                total from transaksi 
                                                where outlet = '".$datanya[$x]."' and tanggal between '$start_date' and '$end_date' order by tanggal desc");
                    foreach($hasil as $hsl)
                        {
                            $result[] = $hsl;
                        }
            }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

And here is My JavaScript

```
$('.changeschanges').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
                 url: '<?=base_url();?>graph/onchange',
                 data: {datanya:$(".select2").val(),tgl:$("#reservation").val()},
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'JSON',
                 success: function(data) {
                      $.each(data, function(k, v) { 
                     res.push(data[k].outlet,[data[k].tanggal, data[k].total])
            });
              $.each(data, function(k, v) { 
                     date.push([data[k].tanggal])
            });
             $.each(data, function(y, x) { 
                     otl.push([data[y].outlet])
            });

                $('#container').highcharts({
                                title: {
                                    text: '',
                                    x: -20
                                },
                                subtitle: {
                                    text: 'Perbanding Grafik Pendapatan',
                                    x: -20
                                },
                                xAxis: {
                                 categories: date
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Rupiah (Rp.)'
                                    },
                                    plotLines: [{
                                        value: 0,
                                        width: 1,
                                        color: '#808080'
                                    }]
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    valueSuffix: ' Rupiah'
                                },
                                legend: {
                                    layout: 'vertical',
                                    align: 'right',
                                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                                    borderWidth: 0
                                },

                                series: [{
                                    name: 'Outlet '+ otl,
                                    data: res

                                }]

                            });
                            setTimeout(function () {
        }, 1000);
        },

    });
    });
```

I was able to create ajax with this ajax result

```
 [{"tanggal":"2016-04-03","total":5371010},
     {"tanggal":"2016-04-02","total":6387090},
     {"tanggal":"2016-04-01","total":2116550}]
```

why i adding `outlet` inside my newest ajax result (at the top). Because there will be multiple line `K-SM3 & K-PKM`. Sorry for my bad english.

It's the result example

[image]

Comment: Right now you have wrong format of your data (and your series name as well). Here you can find information how your data should look: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series 
You can make more than one series in your chart, or add parameters in existing series, but you cannot use format of data: [array, [array,array]] Because Highcharts will not be able to plot your data.

Comment: its because of `" "`, you should try `<?php $var = json_encode(json_decode(your_result')) ?>`

Comment: @SonuBamniya the json that the OP posted is valid json - the numeric values are not quoted, and the quotes around the text values are not the problem. The problem is that the format is not a format that Highcharts can interpret, and the comment by Grzegorz shows how it needs to be formatted.

Comment: i'm bit confused. I think i'm going to change my query so i can match the valid format.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński can you help me for making the queries?

Comment: I think that you may change function responsible for making your data from your ajax result. Here you can see an example how you can change it: http://jsfiddle.net/s2zqf655/